# How to generate a hash of an RDF graph using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, triplestore

I have an RDF ontology in a triplestore that users can make changes to. I want to increment/alter the ontology version with each change. One way to do it would be to use a hash of the ontology graph as the version. For that I need to calculate a hash of the RDF graph using SPARQL, as that is the only available API.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing how well this approach worked in practice. You don't need to bump the version if someone only fixed a typo in a comment, and you don't know how big the change was just from a differing hash.

Comment: I refactored the query below into an update that hashes all ontology terms and sets the `owl:versionInfo` to that value. I tried https://dydra.com as well as Fuseki and on a small dataset (20000 triples) it was really quick. Haven't tried scaling it beyond that as I'm considering an alternative approach which would not require hashing.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this can be addressed in 2 steps:

- generating a stable serialization of the graph (e.g. N-Triples with a stable ordering) using SPARQL
- applying one of the SPARQL [hash functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-hash) to get the actual hash value

Following [suggestions on Twitter](https://twitter.com/namedgraph/status/1351521880369491968), I came up with this query that seems to generate valid N-Triples:

```
SELECT  (GROUP_CONCAT(?tripleStr ; separator=' \n') AS ?nTriples)
WHERE
  { ?s  ?p  ?o
    BIND(if(isURI(?s), concat("<", str(?s), ">"), concat("_:", str(?s))) AS ?sStr)
    BIND(concat("<", str(?p), ">") AS ?pStr)
    BIND(if(isURI(?o), concat("<", str(?o), ">"), if(isBlank(?o), concat("_:", str(?o)), concat("\"", str(?o), "\"", if(( lang(?o) != "" ), concat("@", str(lang(?o))), concat("^^<", str(datatype(?o)), ">"))))) AS ?oStr)
    BIND(concat(?sStr, " ", ?pStr, " ", ?oStr, " .") AS ?tripleStr)
  }
ORDER BY ?s ?p ?o datatype(?o) lcase(lang(?o))
```

Please do give it a try and report bugs, if any. The approach could be easily extended to N-Quads. *As was pointed out on Twitter, it will not scale to large datasets.*

Now, getting the actual hash of the graph is as easy as changing the `SELECT` criteria to:

```
SELECT (SHA1(GROUP_CONCAT(?tripleStr; separator=" \n")) AS ?graphHash)
```

Here we used the `SHA1` hash function.

Comment: Blank Node labels are implementation specific and can’t be relied on for repeatable ordering.

Comment: @GreggKellogg right, but if we assume URIs only then this approach works?

Comment: Sure, then there’s no ambiguity, or if blank nodes are skolemized.